# threejs. How can i make the bottom face of ConeGeometry to look at some point(x,y,z) in the world?

Tags: three.js

[image]

base on the code of  https://threejs.org/docs/?q=ConeGeometry#api/en/geometries/ConeGeometry

```
ConeGeometry: function (mesh) {

                const data = {
                    radius: 5,
                    height: 10,
                    radialSegments: 8,
                    heightSegments: 1,
                    openEnded: false,
                    thetaStart: 0,
                    thetaLength: twoPi,
                    rotateX: 0,
                    rotateY: 0,
                    rotateZ: 0,
                    lookAtX: 0,
                    lookAtY: 0,
                    lookAtZ: 0,
                };

                function generateGeometry() {
                    const geometry = new ConeGeometry(
                        data.radius,
                        data.height,
                        data.radialSegments,
                        data.heightSegments,
                        data.openEnded,
                        data.thetaStart,
                        data.thetaLength,
                    )
                    // geometry.up = new Vector3(0, 1, 0)
                    // geometry.translate(0, - data.height / 2, 0)
                    const angle = 90 * (Math.PI / 180);

                    // Rotate the geometry
                    geometry.rotateX(data.rotateX);
                    geometry.rotateY(data.rotateY);
                    geometry.rotateZ(data.rotateZ);


                    const lookAtVector = new Vector3(data.lookAtX, data.lookAtY, data.lookAtZ)
                    geometry.lookAt(lookAtVector)


                    updateGroupGeometry(mesh,
                        geometry
                    );

                }
```

I have used the lookAt method, but the performance does not meet my expectations. The direction of lookAt is not the normal vector of the base of the cone.

Comment: It's not clear, what the desired result. Do you want to rotate a cone awhole? Or just its base?